# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_27_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (55000, 28, 28)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

hi i'm trying to use cnn on fashion mnist data
there are 5200 images 28*28 in grayscale so i used a 2D cnn
here is my code:

```
fashion_mnist=keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(xtrain,ytrain),(xtest,ytest)=fashion_mnist.load_data()
xvalid,xtrain=xtrain[:5000]/255.0,xtrain[5000:]/255.0
yvalid,ytrain=ytrain[:5000],ytrain[5000:]

defaultcon=partial(keras.layers.Conv2D,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',padding="SAME")

model=keras.models.Sequential([
                           defaultcon(filters=64,kernel_size=7,input_shape=[28,28,1]),
                           keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
                           defaultcon(filters=128),
                           defaultcon(filters=128),
                           keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
                           defaultcon(filters=256),
                           defaultcon(filters=256),
                           keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
                           keras.layers.Flatten(),
                           keras.layers.Dense(units=128,activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                           keras.layers.Dense(units=64,activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                           keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'),

])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history=model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=30,validation_data=(xvalid,yvalid))
```

but i get Error when checking input: expected conv2d_27_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (55000, 28, 28)
how expected to get 4D ?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the dimensions of your data? It seems to be [28,28] when you want [28,28,1]. Try something like xtrain = xtrain[:,:,:,None] and do the same for ytrain (or look at np.reshape or np.expand_dims).

Comment: i used xtrain=np.expand_dims(xtrain,axis=3) and tried all axis but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the input line :

```
defaultcon(filters=64,kernel_size=7,input_shape=[28,28,1])
```

you mistakenly defined the shape (28,28,1) which is not correct. And for a task with **m** samples, model will expect the data with the dimension of (m,28,28,1) which is a 4D.

Apparently your inputs are in the shape of (m,28,28) where m is the number of samples. So you can solve your problem by changing the line I mentioned above with this one:

```
defaultcon(filters=64,kernel_size=7,input_shape=(28,28))
```

and hopefully, you will be all set.

Comment: thanks for your response but i already tried that and it didn't work!

Comment: another error will happen that shape of input and pooling is incorrect

Comment: What is the error? can you copy/paste the error here?

Comment: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Comment: Are you sure you have changed it as I have mentioned? It seems it did not got changed. If you go with shape=(28,28), it is impossible to get a 4D expected error